# ¿Como incrementar contador dentro de un "this.setState"?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Cada vez que se pulse el botón con la palabra "Increment!" quiero que se vaya sumando 1. Haciendo esto cuando se pulsa el botón simplemente cambia a 1. Pero quiero que haga funcionalidad de contador. Pero dentro de `setState` no puedo declarar una variable tipo `"{count = count +1"` , no? Y si se se puede como hacer saber al programa que es el count del componente?

```js
increment() {
    this.setState({
      count: 1 })
}
```

**Aquí el código completo:**

```js
class Counter extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      count: 0
    };
    
    this.increment = this.increment.bind(this);
    
  }
  
increment() {
    this.setState({
      count: 1 })
}
  
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button className='inc' onClick={this.increment}>Increment!</button>
        <button className='dec' onClick={this.decrement}>Decrement!</button>
        <button className='reset' onClick={this.reset}>Reset</button>
        <h1>Current Count: {this.state.count}</h1>
      </div>
    );
  }
};
```

Answer (score 5):

No estás añadiendo 1, estás seteando el valor del state al valor 1:

Debes añadir 1 a tu variable `count`. Además, es recomentable comprobar el estado previo (`prevState`) para que la operación sea atómica:

```
increment() {
    this.setState(prevState=>({
  count:prevState.count +1
  }));
}
```

Te dejo un enlace funcionando [aquí](https://jscomplete.com/playground/s223478)